# Mysql search fields different order

Tags: php, mysql, sql, innodb

I have a table like this

```
name  | surname   | email         | tel
Edwin | Williams  | edwin@aa.com  | 123456
Luke  | Evan      | luke@bb.com   | 987456
```

I need to search "Edwin Williams" or "Williams Edwin" as the same.

I tried

```
CONCAT_WS (' ', name, surname, email, email2) LIKE '%".addslashes($_POST['search'])."%'
OR
CONCAT_WS (' ', surname, name, email, email2) LIKE '%".addslashes($_POST['search'])."%'
```

but I don't like it, in I search "123456 Edwin" I don't find anything.

I have table in InnoDb, I prefer not use MyISAM fulltext.

Comment: `WHERE (name='Edwin' and surname='Williams') OR (surname='Edwin' and name='Williams')`

Comment: you compare "123456 Edwin" to "Edwin Williams edwin@aa.com 123456" OR "Williams Edwin edwin@aa.com 123456", no result

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
WHERE CONCAT_WS(' ', name, surname, email, email2, tel) REGEXP REPLACE(CONCAT('%', $_POST['search'], '%'), ' ', '|')
```

You want a vertical bar to get "OR" for a regular expression.

Comment: it does not work if I search "123456 Edwin", it work only for singular column, not for search in multimple